# Restart the SQL Server while rollback

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I killed a process that was running a for while, after I killed the process now it stared to rollback and this is taking time again. Will it be fine if I restart the SQL Server, what will happen to data if I restart the server, will the data in the database will be corrupted or will it cause any other issues.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let the rollback finish.

Comment: You can check roughly how long the rollback is going to take by running `KILL [the relevant spid] WITH STATUSONLY`

Comment: A proper database is designed not to get corrupted by a restart. But the rollback is something that has to finish anyway. (the transactions with its rollbacks are actually the reason a proper database does not get corrupted easily)

Comment: I did not know about that, @Diado - thanks for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 2):

The rollback must be processed. Restarting the server will only cause additional delay. When the server starts it keeps working on the rollback. But before that it will roll forwards through the transaction log the entire transaction up to the point where you killed it.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be fine if I restart the SQL Server,

*Almost* certainly.

The server should be fine but all you'll have done is wasted the time it already spent, since it's just going to startup again and restart the rollback.

Note the "almost" above. While SQL Server is very resilient, I wouldn't intentionally kill it while it's busy, since the best you'll get is a longer wait, and you might get a corrupted database.